# mysql inbuilt function to strip off tags

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1

I have the following sql query in my code:

```
SELECT ANSWER FROM FAQ WHERE (ANSWER LIKE '%".$searchKey."%')
```

Where ANSWER might contains html & style tags also which makes the above query to retrieve nothing though the plain text matches. I am using **Symfony 1.1** and the above query resides in `faq.php` file.

So can anybody suggest how can i overcome this problem?

Comment: No such function, sorry. How about keeping a plaintext copy of `answer`?

Comment: Ever considered an update? Symfony 1.1 is not _supported_ for 3 years now (at least the latest _security_ updates are "only" 2 years old :D)! Don't say, that you should use symfony2, but at least 1.3, or 1.4 should let you sleep much better :D

Comment: @KingCrunch sf1.1 still use the old form system wich can be a nightmare to migrate to sf1.3/4. But I agree with you.

Comment: @j0k I know what, you mean, but migrating the forms _can_ be a nightmare, but a compromised system _will_ be a nightmare ;) In my opinion from time to time there is no way around an update. I for myself prefer continous updates, which keeps the nightmares small (but maybe they comes more often ^^)

Comment: Hi Piskvor, keeping a pain text copy of answer won't work fine at the time of editing it later on since it looses all the style tags the user had given and annoys them a bit, isn't it?

Comment: "if you have spent a lot of time to resolve the task you are going in the wrong way" &copy;

Answer (score 0):

I originally said:

```
"SELECT `answer` FROM `faq` WHERE (`answer` LIKE '%".strip_tags($searchKey)."%'")
```

but now this is what has been added due to comments..

Why not do something like this then?

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `answer` FROM `faq` WHERE (`answer` LIKE '%$searchKey%'");
while ($result = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
    $newStrippedItem = strip_tags($result->columnItemName);
}
```

Comment: hi, i got your idea but $searchKey as such is a plain text. I wanted to do strip_tags(answer)..!

Comment: You should rather do it after you have returned your data to the application. So once you have got the record-set into a $result, apply all the logic to each item you need. I will amend my answer to show what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is use the `PHP` function `htmlentities(answer)`.
It will display the `HTML` tags as plain text.

Hope it helps,

Bram

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function off the shelf. While it *could* be written, it would be much more performant to prepare a "simplified" version of ANSWER and run a fulltext matching on that one. After all, the search would take place on a strip_tag'ed version of ANSWER: be it is generated by a mysql_strip_tag function or stored in a ANSWER_SIMPLE column, the logic is the same.

On searching, you e.g. strip tags, remove noise-words, and lowercase SearchQuery, then look for your SimplifiedSearchQuery within ANSWER_SIMPLE. You might also do other tricks such as convert all words to their Soundex form before storing, and search (optionally?) for "similarities".

Another possibility is to chunk SearchQuery into single words and search them separately. So if the HTMLised Answer does not match because you have, say, "But {em}I{/em} am your {em}Queen{/em}!", where the SearchQuery "your Queen" won't be found, you can search for matches for **both** "your" and "Queen". This will entail false positives, but allows you to employ your current database without resorting to a stripped ancillary column or table.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know this is old but, I think you could solve your problem by creating this function on `mysql`:

```
DELIMITER |
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS plain_text |
CREATE FUNCTION plain_text( Dirty text )
RETURNS text
DETERMINISTIC 
BEGIN
  DECLARE iStart, iEnd, iLength int;
    WHILE Locate( '<', Dirty ) > 0 And Locate( '>', Dirty, Locate( '<', Dirty )) > 0 DO
      BEGIN
        SET iStart = Locate( '<style>', Dirty ), iEnd = Locate( '</style>', Dirty);
        IF iEnd > 0 THEN
            BEGIN
                SET iLength = ( iEnd - iStart) + 12;
            END;
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET iStart = Locate( '<', Dirty ), iEnd = Locate( '>', Dirty, Locate('<', Dirty ));
                SET iLength = ( iEnd - iStart) + 1;
            END;
        END IF;
        IF iLength > 0 THEN
          BEGIN
            SET Dirty = Insert( Dirty, iStart, iLength, '');
          END;
        END IF;
      END;
    END WHILE;
    RETURN Dirty;
END;
|
DELIMITER ;
```

This function removes all the html tags and everything that is between `<style></style>` tags.

Then you could do your query like this:

```
SELECT plain_text(ANSWER) as plain_t FROM FAQ HAVING (plain_t LIKE '%".$searchKey."%')
```